# Google App Engine handling parallel requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webserver, parallel-processing

I am using Google App Engine for the first time, whenever I make requests using two instances of the application, the responses come sequentially.. 
For example, I opened two pages of the app's main page, made an AJAX request from one then refreshed the other, the page doesn't load until the first page gets its response.. so the server actually waits and responds to requests sequentially..

Is this an issue with the development server only? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python `dev_appserver` is single-threaded and only serves one request at a time. The production environment, naturally, has no such restriction.

Comment: I've just uploaded my work and it still replies to requests sequentially.. I opened the page from different browsers and some requests took up to 22 seconds to get replied to.. just because other requests were still being handled

Comment: @MohamedKhamis App engine does not serialize requests in production. It wouldn't be a particularly scalable platform if it did.